# How to get MDI window title bars on Windows 10 with a modern look

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm maintaining and old software that has an MDI interface (yes, I know it's out of fashion today) and I'd like the MDI title bars have a modern look on Windows 10.

This is the actual look (upper corner if the application's main window with the upper corner if an MDI winow):

[image]

And this is the look I'd like to get:

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve this other than doing all the painting stuff of the non client area myself.

Comment: I've seen this question asked before, but in the context of Delphi. I think the answer is the same, namely that the system does not support what you want.

Comment: The upside of Windows is that old stuff will run forever. The downside is that old stuff will look old. Read [Joel On Software: Fire and Motion](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/01/06/fire-and-motion/), particularly about 2/3 of the way down you might find it relevant.

Comment: If it is just for your computer you could install Windows Blinds. My MDI applications render according to the skin I am using. No coding.

Comment: Useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610613/why-arent-my-mdi-child-forms-showing-a-shadow