# Old Visual Studio 2017/MFC application still has a very old "look" to the windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I have a 32bit MFC C++ application that was originally developed 25 years ago. The windows still have a very old look and feel to them with thick rounded edges, I think dating back to XP. The dialogs are better, especially since I added the following:

**#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")**

Is there a way to update the look and feel of the windows? Here is an example of a resizable window …

[image]

Comment: Please confirm you're asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016180/how-to-get-mdi-window-title-bars-on-windows-10-with-a-modern-look)

Comment: Yes, seems to be the same problem, and according to that post there seems to be no solution which surprises me. The odd thing is that the dialogs in my application all look pretty good, it is just the windows, as above.

Comment: MDI has long been deprecated. MS actively won't spend time and money developing it.

Comment: It does seem the problematic windows are derived from CMDIChildWnd, and many of these windows in my app are really simple. Is there a way to upgrade them without too much code re-writing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MFC's [Visualization Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/visualization-manager?view=vs-2017) to change the looks of your windows, toolbars, …

The best way to try this out would be to use the [MFC Application Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/mfc-application-wizard?view=vs-2017) to create an empty project of the type you need (SDI / MDI / Dialog based) and take a look at the generated project.

What I see in our MDI application when I select Office 2007\Blue:
[image]

Comment: I built a new app and tried using ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_XP and ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_WINDOWS_7 which both seemed to have the identical old look. I also tried using CMDIChildWndEx which seemed identical to CMDIChildWnd. Is there not another class or something I can use that is a bit more up-to-date? Many of my windows just output simple text. It seems odd that the dialogs and program window all look good, but these CMDIChildWnd windows look so old!

Comment: I'm not sure how you generated your project, I have edited my answer to show how our MDI application looks

Comment: I just build a new MDI app using VS2017 wizard. The program window looks fine, but the CMDIChildWndEx windows still have old style thick frames and rounded top edges. Setting theApp.m_nAppLook to different values affects the program windows, but not the CMDIChildWndEx windows.  Anotehr way forward maybe if there is an alternative to CMDIChildWndEx for building simple windows?