# Visual Studio 2017 / MFC - how to replace CMDIChildWndEx windows to get a more modern look

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, mdi

I have a 20 year old MFC application, currently running on Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10.  Whereas the dialogs look pretty modern, the CMDIChildWndEx windows look very old with thick frames and rounded corners. Apparently this is because the MDI interface is no longer supported. Many of my CMDIChildWndEx windows have very simple functionality and could probably be replaced entirely. But the questions is, what would I replace them with to get a more modern look? Or better still is there a way to just update CMDIChildWndEx?

FWIW I have specified the following #pragma which improved the dialogs, but made no difference to the CMDIChildWndEx windows:
**#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language=''\"")**

[image]

Comment: Use tabbed MDI... or use docking floating windows...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't my MDI child forms showing a shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610613/why-arent-my-mdi-child-forms-showing-a-shadow)

Comment: thank you and excuse my ignorance, but what class would I base a floating window on? I need it to be resizable and scrollable. But I don't need toolbars, menus or tabbing .. Preferably a class that requires minimal changes from CMDIChildWnd!

Comment: Probably rather a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016180/how-to-get-mdi-window-title-bars-on-windows-10-with-a-modern-look. No real solution though...

Comment: So what in practice do people do? I don't see any applications these days with these old windows styles. And I see MFC is still an option in VS2017, and the default app created by the Project Wizard also has these old windows!